# error in mysql partitioning

Tags: mysql, database, database-partitioning

I need to create the table in the below format. But is returning the error in the partitioning area that is `Error Code: 1659. Field 'fldassigndate' is of a not allowed type for this type of partitioning`. How to resolve this error and make partitioning ?

```
CREATE TABLE tblattendancesetup (
  fldattendanceid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  flddept varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldemployee varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldintime varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldouttime varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldlateafter varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldearlybefore varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldweekoff varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldshiftname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldassigndate varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldfromdate varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldtodate varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fldrefid varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY fldattendanceid (fldattendanceid),
  KEY in_attendancesetup (fldemployee,fldintime,fldouttime,fldlateafter,fldearlybefore,fldfromdate,fldtodate,fldattendanceid),
  KEY i_emp_tmp (fldemployee),
  KEY i_emp_attendance (fldemployee)
)
 PARTITION BY RANGE (fldassigndate)
(PARTITION p_Apr VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-05-01')),
 PARTITION p_May VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-06-01')),
 PARTITION p_Nov VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

Comment: Why are all your date columns VARCHAR(20)? What would `MAXVALUE` mean to a field which can store arbitrary text?

Comment: Did you research this? The answer is easy to find with a simple search.

Answer (score 4):

From the MySQL manual (Section 18):

> Data type of partitioning key.  A partitioning key must be either an
>   integer column or an expression that resolves to an integer.

Neither dates nor varchars can be used for partitioning

Comment: I was changed the data type to `date`. Add that column to unique key and to_days function. so. It is working fine. But. I have doubt that How the partition will work if that column's data type will be varchar ?

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is very old, I thought it'd help those searching, like I was at one point.

OP should first set his column structures correctly by using a correct structure for a date field, like datetime.

Once that is done, I have not tried to set my keys in that manner, but I have found that I needed to use a composite primary key if I wanted to keep the structure of my table the same. In this case, it'd be

```
PRIMARY KEY(`fldattendanceid`, `fldassigndate`)
```

Then, there is a missing TO_DAYS specified in the PARTITION BY RANGE. Lastly, I'm not 100 percent sure, but I don't think you can partition on a null field. Even if you can, it'd be awful practice to do so.

```
    CREATE TABLE tblattendancesetup (
    fldattendanceid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    flddept VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    fldemployee VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    fldintime DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldouttime DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldlateafter DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldearlybefore DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldweekoff VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    fldshiftname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    fldassigndate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    fldfromdate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldtodate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    fldrefid VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`fldattendanceid`, `fldassigndate`),
    KEY in_attendancesetup     (fldemployee,fldintime,fldouttime,fldlateafter,fldearlybefore,fldfromdate,fldtodate,fldattendanceid),
  KEY i_emp_tmp (fldemployee),
  KEY i_emp_attendance (fldemployee)
)
 PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(fldassigndate))
(PARTITION p_Apr VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-05-01')),
 PARTITION p_May VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-06-01')),
 PARTITION p_Nov VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

I hope this helps someone!